# Save highchart's legend hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts

I save the highchart's graphic as svg.

```
var chart = $('#graphicName').highcharts();

EXPORT_WIDTH = 1000;

render_width = EXPORT_WIDTH;
render_height = render_width * chart.chartHeight / chart.chartWidth;
var svg = chart.getSVG({
  exporting: {
    sourceWidth: chart.chartWidth,
    sourceHeight: chart.chartHeight
  }
});
```

Ok, now I would like download the highchart's legend but it should be hidden. I don't know if highcharts has an option to do this.

Thanks any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "download the highchart's legend but it should be hidden?" How would user unhide the legend in a static image?

Comment: Yes, in the page I don't show the legend because i do in other table with other method. And in the download I want display the legend with the chart. Is strange, but is my boss's idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by modifying the [chartOptions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions) in your export call:

```
var chart = $('#graphicName').highcharts();

    EXPORT_WIDTH = 1000;

    render_width = EXPORT_WIDTH;
    render_height = render_width * chart.chartHeight / chart.chartWidth;
    var svg = chart.getSVG({
      exporting: {
        sourceWidth: chart.chartWidth,
        sourceHeight: chart.chartHeight,
        chartOptions: {
            legend: {
                enabled: true
            }
         }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What did it do? Any errors? Do you have the legend populated in your chart and `legend: {enabled: false}` set in your chart?

Comment: Any errors, yes, I have this in chart: legend: {
          labelFormatter: function () {
            for(i in gData){
              if(this.name == gData[i].id)
              return gData[i].nom_servicio;
            }
          },
          align: 'left',
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          enabled: false,
        },

and your code in "exporting", but the highchart is saved without legend.

Comment: @OscarLT Can you put up a jsFiddle with representative code/data so I can duplicate your scenario?

Comment: Wow, in jsfiddle works, so the wrong could be in the function where I call to exporting, I will look at there. I give you point and stick, thanks.